# How to get a good current VMWare browser appliance?

Tags: firefox, browser, vmware

I'd like to have a small VMWare virtual machine that runs a copy of Firefox, with Flash enabled.  (Or some equivalently-capable browser.)  I tried doing some Google searching with no luck finding good keywords, and tried looking through VMWare's "marketplace" of VMs, but all I found were things from 2006 or so.

Is there a reasonably easy way to get a current one?  Ideally, I'd like to just download one somewhere, but in the alternative, a quick how-to guide would be useful.

I know I could go through the whole process of getting a full-Linux-install VM and setting things up, but that seems like quite a lot of trouble and ends up with a pretty heavyweight solution to the problem, so I'm hoping there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [firefox browser](http://wiki.rpath.com/wiki/Appliance:Browser_Appliance) appliance is one option. it is old, so you'll have to spend time updating it. you could also try the [chrome os](http://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2009/11/google-chrome-os-running-on-vmware-workstation.html) appliance.

i bet downloading a [ubuntu vm](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/435013) and installing firefox will be a lot easier.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like it would be easier.  Thanks for the direct links!

Answer (score 2):

A [Firefox 3.6 Browser Appliance](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/507083) was released in April 2010 on the VMware Virtual Appliance Marketplace. It is easy to upgrade firefox to the latest version and install the latest flash plugin from within the virtual machine, as explained in the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

http://browser.shell.tor.hu/

Seems to have up to date appliances available